# What's the best way to pass big data into C# functions?

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a very large `byte[]` and a class of helper functions.

Am I right in thinking if I call `Helpers.HelperFunc(mybigbytearray)`, `mybigbytearray` will be duplicated in memory?

If so, what's the best way to give a big variable to a function (pointers look good but is making the helper functions `unsafe` wise? Would the garbage collector still work?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays, like other objects in C#, are passed by reference, thus no data inside the array will be duplicated; the function you pass the array to will have a reference to the original array.

---

From [Arrays as Objects (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2z4khca9.aspx)

> In C#, arrays are actually objects, and not just addressable regions of contiguous memory as in C and C++. System.Array is the abstract base type of all array types.

and [Passing Arrays as Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hyfeyz71.aspx)

> Arrays can be passed as arguments to method parameters. Because arrays are reference types, the method can change the value of the elements.